# Defining Custom iOS Keyboard Key Variant ~ f/w 4.x+

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, keyboard, jailbreak

Some Keys on the iOS keyboard, when pressed and held for a second or so, revile Variants to the character being selected (see link) https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Hh4t.jpg

I'm curious to know if there is a certain way to add/remove to these variants - of course with **Jailbreak.** (It's impossible without J/B)

For Example, is there a way to add to the Key "l" when held to revile the string "lol"?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by simply editing a plist file in System-> Library-> Frameworks-> UIKit.framework and chose your keyboard plist file and add a string under 'Roman-Accent-I'

Do Not try this if you don't know what u r doing

Comment: Found it: /System/Library/TextInput/TextInput_ar.bundle/Key----ar.plist

Answer (score 0):

I would try and figure out how these guys did it and go from there?

http://www.iphonehacks.com/2009/02/jailbreak-app-5row-qwerty-keyboard-adds-another-row-of-keys-to-iphones-virtual-keyboard.html

Comment: I've been rummaging through their .plists and I can't seem to figure out how they've done it. They're adding .keyboard plists to the UIKit.Framework folder.

Comment: are you looking at what those .keyboard files look like? Modify those

Answer (score 0):

There's a package called [Vmoji](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2011/02/18/enable-unicode-symbols-with-vmoji/) that adds extra key variants - it might be worth a look to help you figure out what's going on, or contacting the developer might be helpful.